# React-Redux useSelector strange behavior on tests

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm testing my app with react-native-testing-library, and I found something quite strange for me :

Here is the test :

Loading, go from false, to true, then false again.
But when loading become false again, component does not re-render

```
    const { update, getByTestId, getByText } = render(
      <StoreProvider store={store}>
        <ContactsContainer />
      </StoreProvider>,
    );

    await waitForExpect(() => {
      expect(store.getState().contacts.loading).toEqual(true);
    });

    await waitForElement(() => getByTestId('placeholder'));

    await waitForExpect(() => {
      expect(store.getState().contacts.loading).toEqual(false);
    });

    await expect(
      waitForElement(() => getByTestId('placeholder'), 100),
    ).rejects.toThrow();
```

```
const isLoading = useSelector((state: IAppState) => loadingSelector(state));
```

With this code, during tests, component is re-rendering correctly.

```
const isLoading = useSelector(loadingSelector);
```

With this code, component miss a render, and then tests fails

Does someone have an idea a render is missing ?